# DataTable is exceeding my modal width

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, datatables

Good day everyone,

Im having problem working with datatable inside a modal. If it has a few column it works fine but if the width of all the columns is larger than the width of he modal it goes messy. please see the image
[image]

any help will be appreciated

Here is code for my table:

```
<div class="modal" role="dialog" id="modalDeleveryReceiptView_SelectDeliveredBy">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h3 class="modal-title">Employee Selection</h3>
                </div><!--modal header-->
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <table id="tblDeliveryReceiptView_EmployeeSelection"class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Emp #.</th>
                                <th>First Name</th>
                                <th>Middle Name</th>
                                <th>LastName</th>
                                <th>Gender></th>
                                <th>Job Title</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                            <tr>
                                <td>EMP-16-000001</td>
                                <td>Exequiel</td>
                                <td>Santos</td>
                                <td>Cuevas</td>
                                <td>Male</td>
                                <td>Dev</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>EMP-16-000001</td>
                                <td>Exequiel</td>
                                <td>Santos</td>
                                <td>Cuevas</td>
                                <td>Male</td>
                                <td>Dev</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>EMP-16-000001</td>
                                <td>Exequiel</td>
                                <td>Santos</td>
                                <td>Cuevas</td>
                                <td>Male</td>
                                <td>Dev</td>
                            </tr>

                    </table><!--Employee Selection table-->
                </div><!--modal body-->
            </div><!--modal content-->
        </div><!--modal dialog-->
    </div><!--modal Select Delivered By-->
```

Here is my Script:

```
$('#tblDeliveryReceiptView_EmployeeSelection').DataTable({
    "paging": false,
    "info": false,
    "searching": true,
    "autoWidth": false
});
```

I want it to become like this:
[image]
Where the exceeding columns is placed inside a child row that will only be visible if you click the plus button

Comment: Can you post the CSS code as well? We may find an answer using that. Also, what happens if you set `autoWidth` to true?

Comment: Try adding width="100%" into the <table> opening tag. You may also want to take out the 'nowrap'. Another option is overwriting the default datatables CSS with overflow:scroll or overflow:hidden - If i remember correctly though datatables has support for cutting columns in a responsive layout..

Comment: have you tried add css overflow-x:auto in <div class="modal-body"> ?

Comment: The "overflow-x:auto" eliminate the exceeding column but it generate a scrollbar and that is not what i want to happen. in my other datatables (that is not in the modal), the exceeding columns is placed inside a child row that will be visible when you clicked a generated button. I'll update my question to make sense.

PS: I didn't yet add CSS to this thats why i didn't bother to share the CSS code, but if you need a specific css code just let me know

Comment: Question had been updated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and this code fixed my problem.

```js
$(modal-selector).on('shown.bs.modal', function () {

  var table = $('#tblDeliveryReceiptView_EmployeeSelection').DataTable({
    paging: false,
    info: false,
    searching: true,
    autoWidth: false
 });

 table.columns.adjust().draw();

});
```

Comment: autoWidth: false is fixed mine also

Answer (score 0):

You should set the property `overflow-x` to `auto` in `<div class="modal-body">` as @monerico commented on your question, this way:

`overflow-x:auto;`

Additionally, you may want to increase the width of the modal itself to show the complete content of the table.

Please share your CSS for further help.